# Set the maximum amount limit on a UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I know how to put character length limit on UITextField. But I am looking for an idea how to put amount limit on UITextField so that it can not take more than that limited amount.

I want to put limit on TextField that can accept value in between 0 to 1000000

I tried to get it using **UITextFieldDelegate's** method

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if let amount = Int(textField.text!) ,amount>1000000{
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

but I am not able to achieve the result.

Comment: Maybe you are looking this ``` let amount = Int((textField.text ?? "") + string) ?? 0
        if (0 < amount) && (amount < 1000000) {
            return true
        }
        return false```

Comment: this code should work, make sure this method gets called. If it's not, make sure you're setting the correct object for a  text field `delegate`

Comment: also `1000000` is a huge number, I'd test on something like 10 to make sure it works at first

Comment: @RajaKishan yes it worked...I was missing to add incoming string Thanks

Comment: I think your requirement is to allow the user to enter amounts only between 0 to 1000000 right?

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the current string too with text field value.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if let text = textField.text,
           let amount = Int((text + string).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)),
           (0 < amount), (amount < 1000000) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```